# Allow storage of any JSON file regardless of how it is defiened

Tags: json, mongodb

Currently the rest endpoint that we use to update out data base accepts only properly defined JSON formats. Is there a simple way to store any JSON file into the DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MongoDB` stores data in `BSON` format which is similar to JSON. You can store data in JSON format and can make a query on any field

`MySQL` (5.7) has native JSON datatype. [check it](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json.html)

But remember JSON is just a serialization technique, You can always keep it like string in your DB, but i not see reason to do it.